# Remove content-disposition and *filename from MultipartFormDataContent

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create a POST request using .Net 5 in the following format:

POST
[https://someLMShost.edu/d2l/api/le/{version}/{orgUnit}/content/modules/{moduleId}/structure/](https://someLMShost.edu/d2l/api/le/%7Bversion%7D/%7BorgUnit%7D/content/modules/%7BmoduleId%7D/structure/)
HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=xxBOUNDARYxx
Content-Length: {POST body in length in bytes}

--xxBOUNDARYxx
Content-Type: application/json

{"IsHidden": false, "IsLocked": false, "ShortTitle": "Test", "Type": 1,
"DueDate": null, "Url": "/content/extensibility/EXT-104/file.txt",
"StartDate": null, "TopicType": 1, "EndDate": null, "Title": "Test topic
content"}
--xxBOUNDARYxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="file.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

This is a sample text file
with some text content.
--xxBOUNDARYxx--

My code looks like this:

```
var apiResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();

var stringContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
stringContent.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "";
var stringfile = new StringContent(file, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");  
stringfile.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "";

MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    stringContent,
    { stringfile, "\"\"", "\"file.txt\"" }
};

apiResponse = await _client.PostAsync(request, form);
```

My code is producing the following request:

POST
https://instance.desire2learn.com/d2l/api/le/1.60/329015/content/modules/9885759/structure/?x_a=qwerty&x_b=qwerty&x_c=qwert&x_d=qwerty&x_t=qwert HTTP/1.1
Host: instance.desire2learn.com
traceparent: 00-aff8b6564150364bac900043e5f0daa7-a3512fc259a59c49-00
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="27d7ac2d-6f96-4c17-84d8-2a93da333bab"
Content-Length: 565

--27d7ac2d-6f96-4c17-84d8-2a93da333bab
Content-Type: application/json
**Content-Disposition: form-data**

{"Title":"Test topic content","ShortTitle":"Test","Type":1,"TopicType":1,"Url":"/content/enforced/Sandbox/testHTML.html","StartDate":null,"EndDate":null,"DueDate":null,"IsHidden":false,"IsLocked":false}

--27d7ac2d-6f96-4c17-84d8-2a93da333bab
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="file.txt"**; filename*=utf-8''%22file.txt%22**

test
--27d7ac2d-6f96-4c17-84d8-2a93da333bab--

How would I go about removing the bolded parts of the request? "Content-Disposition: form-data" from the first part and "; filename*=utf-8''%22file.txt%22" from the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably *MultipartFormDataContent* is not the right content type for this case. Try using *MultipartContent* like shown below.

```
var stringContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
stringContent.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = string.Empty;

var stringFile = new StringContent(file, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
stringFile.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = string.Empty;
stringFile.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
{
    FileName = file,
    Name = "\"\""
};

var multiPartContent = new MultipartContent
{
    stringContent,
    stringFile
};
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is ok to use a StringContent... and/or build up your headers manually as text, it is still possible (perhaps more correct) to use the MultiPartFormDataContent class but you must use the methods and properties specifically provided for this.  Doing so is arguably neater.

To send a binary file you could do something like this.

```
  MultipartFormDataContent formData;
  HttpClient client;
  FileStream stream;
  HttpContent fileContent;
  HttpRequestMessage request;
  HttpResponseMessage response;
  bool result;

  client = new HttpClient();
  client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
  request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
  string binFile = "myBinary.bin"
  stream = new FileStream(binFile, FileMode.Open);
  try
  {
    fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    // Insert some form data into the content part of the POST message.
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name = "\"file\"";
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(binFile);
    formData.Add(fileContent);
    request.Content = formData;
    
    // Send everything without waiting for acceptance.
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    response = client.Send(request);
  }
  finally
  {
    stream.Close();
  }
  
  result = reponse.IsSuccessStatusCode;
```